# List generator from tagged data

Tags: information-management, knowledge-organization

I am looking for software that generates lists based on tagged data.

For instance, for 2 records stored:

- Chess: `game, fun, entertainment`
- Podcast: `media, audio, entertainment`

If the tag `entertainment` was input, Chess *AND* Podcast would be displayed in the output list. If the tag `fun` was input *ONLY* Chess would be displayed in the list.

1. Input: Tag (such as entertainment, or fun)
2. Output: List (such as chess or podcast)
3. OS: N/A (Web), otherwise OSX
4. Data Storage: Web based, otherwise local
5. Output: Grid on screen
6. Payment: Free is best, otherwise under $10

iTunes does this for songs, but I would like an app that searches data like in the example above.

[*Added*]
I ended up just importing the data into Google Spreadsheet and using the function Query to use SQL statements to output the lists. A nice UI would be nice, but this will do.

Comment: "iTunes does this for songs" Your whole issue here is that you want your tags **not** to be associated with files. There's plenty of taggers for files (e.g. mp3), but you just want to (store and) tag arbitrary strings, right? Sounds like an opportunity for someone to build an app ;-)

Comment: Yeah I'm surprised that this app doesn't exist or at least is not well known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that an app called [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/home/) that does this.  It also allows the list to be shared, which is a welcome bonus.

Comment: Huh? I use Wunderlist. I don't see how that solves your issue, it has no such things as tags? And it is not suited for large amounts of data.

Comment: According to the website it supports tags. And my requirements actually are not for large amounts of data.

Comment: But I see your point that it might have limitations like data importing.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up just importing the data into Google Spreadsheet and using the function `Query` to use SQL statements to output the lists.  A nice UI would be nice, but this will do.

Comment: Could you please share the formulas and a screenshot? Thanks!